# Move to specific div based on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I was trying to move the divs (here it's question number) based on the prev and next button. So that the selected question is always visible on screen.

Here is the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/arunslb123/trxe4n3u/12/

Screen : [image]

click and question number and click prev or next button to understand my issue.

My code :

```
$("#next")
.click(function () {
    $(".c.current-question")
        .each(function () {
            var divIdx = $(this)
                .attr('id');
            var scrollTo = $('#' + divIdx)
                .position()
                .left;
            $("#scrollquestion")
                .animate({
                    'scrollLeft': scrollTo
                }, 800);
        });
});

$("#prev")
.click(function () {
    $(".c.current-question")
        .each(function () {
            var divIdx = $(this)
                .attr('id');
            var scrollTo = $('#' + divIdx)
                .position()
                .left;
            $("#scrollquestion")
                .animate({
                    'scrollLeft': -scrollTo
                }, 800);
        });
});
```

Comment: Have you found your solution yet.

Comment: No. still I'm figuring it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `scrollLeft` is a bit tricky. I did a small redo of your use-case based on positioning and then moving it based on `left` of the container. The tricky part is to reliably calculate the negative position when scrolled to the extreme right. Also, need to take into account the widths and margins.

**Check the below snippet**:

```js
var $wrap = $("#numWrap"), $strip = $("#strip"), 
    $leftArrow = $(".wrapper > .arrows").first(), 
    wrapWidth = $wrap.width() + $leftArrow.width(), 
    margin = 10;
    
fill(20); select($(".numberItem").first());

$strip.on("click", ".numberItem", function() { select($(this)); });

function select($elem) {
    $(".numberItem").removeClass("selected");
    $elem.addClass("visited").addClass("selected");
    focus($elem[0]);    
}

function focus(elem) {
    var stripPos = $strip.position(), 
        numPos = $(elem).offset(), 
        elemWidth = $(elem).width() + margin, 
        numRight = numPos.left + elemWidth;
    
    if (numRight > wrapWidth) {
        $strip.css({"left": stripPos.left - elemWidth}); 
    }
    if (numPos.left < (margin + $leftArrow.width()))  {
        $strip.css({"left": stripPos.left + elemWidth}); 
    }
}

$(".wrapper").on("click", "a.arrow", function() {
    var stripPos = $strip.position();
    if (this.id == "lft") {
        $strip.css({"left": stripPos.left + (wrapWidth / 2)}); 
    } else {
        $strip.css({"left": stripPos.left - (wrapWidth / 2)});
    }
});

$(".controls").on("click", "a.arrow", function() {
    var $sel = $(".selected"), numPos, $sel, elemWidth; 
     $elem = $sel.length > 0 ? $sel.first() : $(".numberItem").first();
    if (this.id == "lft") {
        $sel = $elem.prev().length > 0 ? $elem.prev() : $elem;
        select($sel); 
    } else {
        $sel = $elem.next().length > 0 ? $elem.next() : $elem;
        select($sel);
    }
    numPos = $sel.offset(); elemWidth = $sel.width() + margin;
    numRight = numPos.left + elemWidth;
    if (numPos.left > wrapWidth) {
        $strip.css({"left": -($sel.text()) * $sel.width() });
    }
    if (numRight < 0) {
        $strip.css({"left": +($sel.text()) * $sel.width() });
    }
});

function fill(num){
    for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        var $d = $("<a href='#' class='numberItem'>" + i + "</a>");
        $strip.append($d);
    }
}
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; font-family: sans-serif; }
div.wrapper { 
    background-color: #ddd; width: 100vw; height: 64px; 
    clear: both; overflow: hidden; margin-top: 16px;
}
div.arrows { 
    float: left; width: 10%; min-width: 24px; height: 64px; line-height: 64px;
    text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; overflow: hidden;
}
div.numWrap { 
    float: left; height: 64px; line-height: 64px;
    width: 80%; vertical-align: middle; 
    overflow: hidden; position: relative;
}
div.strip { 
    position: absolute; left: 0px;
    width: auto; white-space: nowrap; 
    transition: left 1s;
}
a.numberItem { 
    display: inline-block; text-align: center; margin: 0px 8px;
    background-color: #fff; border-radius: 50%; width: 48px; height: 48px; 
    font-size: 1.2em; line-height: 48px; text-decoration: none;
}
a.numberItem.visited { background-color: #fff; color: #000; border: 2px solid #01aebc; }
a.numberItem.selected { background-color: #01aebc; color: #fff; }
div.controls { clear: both; }
div.controls > div.arrows { width: auto; margin: 0 12px; }
a, a:focus, a:active, a:link, a:visited { 
    display: inline-block; 
    text-decoration: none; font-weight: 600; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="arrows">
        <a id="lft" class="arrow" href="#">&#x3008;</a>
    </div>
    <div id="numWrap" class="numWrap">
        <div id="strip" class="strip"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="arrows">
        <a id="rgt" class="arrow" href="#">&#x3009;</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="controls">
    <div class="arrows">
        <a id="lft" class="arrow" href="#">&#x3008;&nbsp; Previous</a>
    </div>
    <div class="arrows">
        <a id="rgt" class="arrow" href="#">Next &nbsp;&#x3009;</a>
    </div>    
<div>
```

**Explanation:**

1. Using `absolute` positioning on the number container, which is nested to get `100%` width.

Markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="arrows"><a id="lft" class="arrow" href="#">&#x3008;</a></div>
    <div id="numWrap" class="numWrap">
        <div id="strip" class="strip"></div> <!-- nesting here -->
    </div>
    <div class="arrows"><a id="rgt" class="arrow" href="#">&#x3009;</a></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.wrapper { 
    background-color: #ddd; width: 100vw; height: 64px; 
    clear: both; overflow: hidden; margin-top: 16px;
}
div.arrows { 
    float: left; width: 10%; min-width: 24px; height: 64px; line-height: 64px;
    text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; overflow: hidden;
}
div.numWrap { 
    float: left; height: 64px; line-height: 64px;
    width: 80%; vertical-align: middle; 
    overflow: hidden; position: relative; /* relatively positioned */
}
div.strip { 
    position: absolute; left: 0px;        /* absolutely positioned */
    width: auto; white-space: nowrap; 
    transition: left 1s;                  /* instead of jquery animate */
}
```

With this structure, we can now use `left` to control the scrolling.

2. For partially obscured numbers, try to gently focus-in (nudge into view) a number which is partially obscured. This can be done by checking the `position` relative to parent and adding the width/margin to it and also accounting for width of the left arrow (it might peep thru).

Javascript:

```
function focus(elem) {
    var stripPos = $strip.position(), 
        numPos = $(elem).offset(), 
        elemWidth = $(elem).width() + margin, 
        numRight = numPos.left + elemWidth;

    // if it is towards right side, nudge it back inside
    if (numRight > wrapWidth) {
        $strip.css({"left": stripPos.left - elemWidth}); 
    } 
    // if it is towards left side, nudge it back inside
    if (numPos.left < (margin + $leftArrow.width()))  {
        $strip.css({"left": stripPos.left + elemWidth}); 
    } 
}
```

3. Once the user has scrolled the list too far and then tries to click on *previous / next* buttons to select a question, then we need to move the entire container upto the selected number. We can easily do this by multiplying the question number with element width and then changing the `left` in positive (*if towards right*) or in negative (*if towards left*).

Javascript:

```
// if left of element is more than the width of parent
if (numPos.left > wrapWidth) {
    $strip.css({"left": -($sel.text()) * $sel.width() });
}
// if right of element is less than 0 i.e. starting position
if (numRight < 0) {
    $strip.css({"left": +($sel.text()) * $sel.width() });
}
```

---

*Here is a fiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/aw166qhx/*

You will need to further adapt it to your use-case, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for spending your time on this. One more question. Is it possible to drag on the question number to navigate left and right in mobile phones?

Comment: @ArunPrakash: You can do that by showing the scrollbar via `overflow-x: scroll;`. Then adding `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` would allow natural scrolling on touch. Adding `-ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;` would auto-hide the scrollbar. Adding a `::-webkit-scrollbar`, you can controll the size of scrollbar on webkit browsers. You can search for more, but this will get you going. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/aw166qhx/1/

Comment: still it's going zig zag. For ex, just choose q.no 20 and drag and move to q.no 1 screen. Now click the next button..... 
2. sometimes touch scroll is not moving to back..it just got struck. Any idea on how to fix this? Demo ; http://arunslb123.github.io/horizontal-scroll-2/#

Comment: @ArunPrakash, I quickly checked and could not reproduce the problem that you are mentioning. It is working just fine. I checked on Chrome, Edge and on my iPhone, Give me some time, I shall check again once I get some time.

Comment: I have created a new question with the issue I'm facing now.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32118723/horizontal-scroll-moving-left-and-right-when-clicking-previous-button Could you please look into the issue in your free time?