# Horizontal scroll moving left and right when clicking previous button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I was trying to move the horizontal scroll left and right when clicking the next and previous button. The problem I'm facing is that the scrolling moves left and right fast when clicking the next or previous buttons.

To reproduce my issue : https://jsfiddle.net/arunslb123/gzaLydkd/

1. Just click question num 36
2. click "previous" button 10-15 times.
3. You can see the horizontal scroll moves here and there.

How to fix this issue?

```
function select($elem) {
$(".numberItem").removeClass("selected");
$elem.addClass("visited").addClass("selected");
focus($elem[0]);
}

function focus(elem) {
var stripPos = $strip.position(),
    numPos = $(elem).offset(),
    elemWidth = $(elem).width() + margin,
    numRight = numPos.left + elemWidth;

if (numRight > wrapWidth) {
    $strip.css({"left": stripPos.left - elemWidth});
  }
if (numPos.left < (margin + $leftArrow.width()))  {
    $strip.css({"left": stripPos.left + elemWidth});
 }
}

$(".controls").on("click", ".button", function() {
var $sel = $(".selected"), numPos, $sel, elemWidth;
  $elem = $sel.length > 0 ? $sel.first() : $(".numberItem").first();
if (this.id == "lft") {
    $sel = $elem.prev().length > 0 ? $elem.prev() : $elem;
    select($sel);
} else {
    $sel = $elem.next().length > 0 ? $elem.next() : $elem;
    select($sel);
}
numPos = $sel.offset(); elemWidth = $sel.width() + margin;
numRight = numPos.left + elemWidth;
if (numPos.left > wrapWidth) {
    $strip.css({"left": -($sel.text()) * $sel.width() });
}
if (numRight < 0) {
    $strip.css({"left": +($sel.text()) * $sel.width() });
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your function to the following, it should keep the next / previous number in the middle of your view:

```
$(".controls").on("click", ".button", function() {
    var $sel = $(".selected"), numPos, $sel, elemWidth;
      $elem = $sel.length > 0 ? $sel.first() : $(".numberItem").first();
    if (this.id == "lft") {
        $sel = $elem.prev().length > 0 ? $elem.prev() : $elem;
        select($sel);
    } else {
        $sel = $elem.next().length > 0 ? $elem.next() : $elem;
        select($sel);
    }
    numPos = $sel.position(); 
    elemWidth = $sel.width() / 2;
    scroll = numPos.left + elemWidth - ($('#numWrap').width() / 2);
    $strip.animate({left: -scroll}, 800);
});
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gzaLydkd/1/)

**Edit**

Scrap the previous stuff as you are mixing moving an absolutely positioned div with a scrolling it's outer div and that will lead to all sorts of problems.  If you just change your js to the following, it should achieve what you want:

```
// same as before
fillQuestion(40);

function fillQuestion(num){
    for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        var $d = $("<a href='#' class='numberItem'>" + i + "</a>");
        $("#strip").append($d);
    }
}

// after you have done your usual stuff, this is where the new code begins
var items = $('.numberItem'),
    selectedIndex = 0,
    scroller = $("#numWrap"),
    scrollerWidth = scroller.width();

selectItem();  // select first item - change the selected index var above to start on a different number

items.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // prevent default action of link
    selectedIndex = items.index($(this)); // set new selected index to this index
    selectItem();
});

$('.controls .btn').on('click', function() {
    var button = $(this);
    if (button.hasClass('prev') && selectedIndex > 0) {
        selectedIndex--;
    } else if (button.hasClass('next') && selectedIndex < items.length - 1) {
        selectedIndex++;
    }

   selectItem();
});

function selectItem() {
    var selected = items.eq(selectedIndex); // set selected item to current selected index
    items.removeClass('selected');  // remove selected from any items
    selected.addClass('visited selected');  // add selected to current item
    focus(selected.position().left);
}

function focus(originalLeft) {
    scroll = originalLeft - (scrollerWidth / 2);
    scroller.stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: scroll
    }, 800);
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gzaLydkd/4/)

Comment: jsfiddle link looks like broken

Comment: hmm, the odd behaviour is fixed, but the scroll bar doesnt show the active number highlighted when previous button is continuously clicked

Comment: @Pete Just click Q.no 38 , now scroll and move to q.no 1. and then click next button. It should go to q.no 39. It does as expected. But now the problem is scroll bar is not working.

Comment: @dreamweiver the multiple clicks (quickly) meant a lot of animations were queued.  Simply fixed by adding `stop()` before animation to clear the queue.  See updated fiddle (scroll will still take the length of the animation to kick in after the last click)

Comment: @ArunPrakash, your whole scrolling thing isn't very good.  You are mixing scrolling an outer div with moving the inner div, you should choose one or the other, not mix both as you end up with a div that has moved inside a div that can scroll

Comment: @Pete: Its my fault actually, (http://stackoverflow.com/a/32099551/1355315). The scrolling requirement wasn't there at first so I suggested a simple carousal-like solution. Op then expressed desire to touch-scroll and I suggested `overflow:scroll` without thinking much. This has created this glitch. When scrolled, the `left` no longer matches with the scroll distance. This needs to be handled with scrolling only.

Comment: @ArunPrakash, I have updated my answer to fix the scrolling and moving div issue and should solve your problem - it only uses scrolling now.

Comment: @Abhitalks updated the js so it should fix the issues

Comment: @Pete: Ohh.. Thanks.. I was about hit submit on my new answer.

Comment: Thank you very much @Pete and Abhitalks :)

Comment: @ArunPrakash I have added some comments to the answer above to explain things a bit

Comment: @Pete Thanks for spending your time and helping me to fix my issues.

Answer (score 2):

The animation is getting called each time the button is clicked to before the animation queue declares a stop

You can use `.stop()` before  `.animate()` to acheive this

```
$("#left-arrow").click(function () {
  var leftPos = $('#numWrap').scrollLeft();
$("#numWrap").stop().animate({scrollLeft: leftPos - 200}, 800);
});

$("#right-arrow").click(function () {
  var leftPos = $('#numWrap').scrollLeft();
$("#numWrap").stop().animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + 200}, 800);
});
```